# SVN Errors on trying to make an initial repository

Tags: svn, repository, svn-repository

First off, my svn version is:
    *svn, version 1.9.3 (r1718519) compiled Aug 10 2017, 16:59:15 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu*

I'm trying to create a repository using svn by following the instructions here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.intro.quickstart.html

When I attempt to make my initial import using the instructions:

```
svn import /tmp/myproject file:///var/svn/repos/myproject -m "initial import"
```

However, when I do this. I get the notices:

> svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///var/svn/repos/myproject'
>   svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///var/svn/repos/myproject'

Comment: Did you `svnadmin create` the repository as described earlier on that page?

Comment: Yes, I did use that command.